# MySQL: Incorrect string value

Tags: debian, mysql, character-encoding

I have been having some problems with some characters in webpages, that we have in UTF8, often in a while.

I am running MySQL 5.7 with Debian 9. My databases are using the `utf8`charset.

Today, when debugging a MySQL query, I ran `SHOW WARNINGS;` and saw in the Message field:

```
 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x8C\x86' for column `xxxx`;
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, Googling for the error, I found a couple of articles suggesting that in MySQL the `utf8` charset is buggy/brain damaged, and should not be used.

In it´s substitution it should be used the `utf8mb4` charset instead.

From [In MySQL, never use “utf8”. Use “utf8mb4”](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434)

> MySQL’s “utf8” isn’t UTF-8.
>
> The “utf8” encoding only supports three bytes per character. The real
>   UTF-8 encoding — which everybody uses, including you — needs up to
>   four bytes per character.
>
> MySQL developers never fixed this bug. They released a workaround in
>   2010: a new character set called “utf8mb4”.
>
> In short:
>    - MySQL’s “utf8mb4” means “UTF-8”.
>    - MySQL’s “utf8” means “a
>   proprietary character encoding”. This encoding can’t encode many
>   Unicode characters.
>
> I’ll make a sweeping statement here: all MySQL and MariaDB users who
>   are currently using “utf8” should actually use “utf8mb4”. Nobody
>   should ever use “utf8”.

From [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

> Turns out MySQL’s utf8 charset only partially implements proper UTF-8
>   encoding. It can only store UTF-8-encoded symbols that consist of one
>   to three bytes; encoded symbols that take up four bytes aren’t
>   supported.
>
> As shown above, this behavior can lead to data loss, but it gets worse — it can result in security vulnerabilities. Here are some examples, all of which were discovered after publishing this write-up:
>
> - PHP object injection vulnerability in WordPress < 3.6.1, leading to remote >code execution in combination with certain WordPress plugins
> - Email authentication bypass in Phabricator Stored XSS in WordPress 4.1.2
> - Remote command execution in the Joomla! CMS
>
> TL;DR MySQL’s `utf8` encoding is awkwardly named, as it’s different from proper UTF-8 encoding. It doesn’t offer full Unicode support, which can lead to data loss or security vulnerabilities.